# CkFinder ASP.NET connector path missing

Tags: asp.net, ckeditor5, ckfinder

The problem is im following the document from ckeditor [here](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckfinder/ckfinder3-net/integration.html)
i downloaded the ckfinder and include it to my project but i cant really find the connector path
now i can browse img but this error appear
Cannot upload file: 7100d0b0652e75392e2fb511d2990b55.jpg.
i think it is because of the upload url
Im using ASP.NET MVC

```
<div class="form-group mt-5">
       <p class="text-center text-dark fw-bolder fs-2 label-font">Recipe &nbsp;Instruction</p>
       <textarea id="editor1" asp-for="Description" class="form-control ckeditor"></textarea>
       <span asp-validation-for="Description" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

```
<script>
    ClassicEditor
        .create(document.querySelector('#editor1'), {
            ckfinder: {
                uploadUrl: '/ckfinder/core/connector/php/connector.php?command=QuickUpload&type=Files&responseType=json',
            },
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error(error);
        });
</script>
```

Additional Question:
Sorry for asking this im not really good at this, i know that the ckeditor will save my description as html type but can i make to save like i save my img

```
<div class="form-group mt-4">
     <label class="mb-2 label-font" asp-for="file">Recipe Image</label>
     <input asp-for="file" class="form-control" type="file" name="file" accept="image/png,image/jpeg" required />
 </div>
```